# Setting Recoverable attribute for MSMQ messages in PHP

Tags: php, message-queue, msmq

I'd like to set a [Recoverable attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.recoverable(v=vs.110).aspx) form messages which I'm sending to MSMQ. I've been searching some resources how to do this in PHP but I haven't found any. I've tried this

```
    if(!$msgOut = new COM("MSMQ.MSMQMessage")){
        return false;
    }           

    $msgOut->Body = $this->getBody(); 
    $msgOut->Label = $this->getLabel();
    $msgOut->Recoverable = true;
    $msgOut->Send($msgQueue);
```

but it does not work. I've also tried to set the boolean as a string value and integer but none of it worked.
When I try `$msgOut->Recoverable = "true";` or `$msgOut->Recoverable = true;` I got com_exception

> Unable to lookup `Recoverable': Unknown name.

Comment: Try with `Recoverable`?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Fixed the spelling, thanks, but it still returns an error.

Comment: I thought it was just a typo, but I guess it won't be that easy :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no recoverable property, so this line is wrong:

```
$msgOut->Recoverable = true;
```

According the documentation of the class [MSMQMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700152(v=vs.85).aspx), the property name should be "Delivery" and value is [MQMSG_DELIVERY_RECOVERABLE](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,725b0385375685ca):

```
public const int MQMSG_DELIVERY_EXPRESS = 0;
public const int MQMSG_DELIVERY_RECOVERABLE = 1;
```

You can send recoverable message in this way:

```
$msgOut->Body = $this->getBody(); 
$msgOut->Label = $this->getLabel();
$msgOut->Delivery = 1;
$msgOut->Send($msgQueue);
```